# Rails form_with select selected option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, form-with

I have a form without a model backing it built using `form_with` in Rails 6:

```erb
<%= f.text_field :one %>

<%= f.select :two, [['Option 1',1],['Option 2',2]] %>

<%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
```

The only documentation I can find to set which of the select options are selected by default says that it will pre-select whatever is in the model. Since I don't have a backing model, how can I choose which option is selected? I've poked around the options a little and found nothing, but I do not necessarily know where to look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have missed it, there's an optional `selected` keyword argument.

> Lastly, we can specify a default choice for the select box with the
> `:selected` argument:
>
> ```
> <%= form.select :city, [["Berlin", "BE"], ["Chicago", "CHI"], ["Madrid", "MD"]], selected: "CHI" %>
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> <select name="city" id="city">
>   <option value="BE">Berlin</option>  
>   <option value="CHI" selected="selected">Chicago</option>
>   <option value="MD">Madrid</option>
> </select>
> ```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

Comment: Thank you. I missed that, however I had tried a `selected` option with no luck. Looking again, it didn't work because I passed it in the `html_options` hash instead of the `options` hash!